# How to change usename on Postfix without create user

Tags: server, 20.04, postfix

Config: Ubuntu Server 22

When we receive an email, it shows the following: FROM User name@domain.com.

This 'User' is the username of the user who was logged into the system before sending the email. For example, if I send an email while logged in as the 'root' user and create an alias like no-reply@domain.com, when I receive the email, it appears as root no-reply@domain.com. So, my question is, can I change this simply by creating a new user on the system and logging in with that user?

main.cf:

```
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name

biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, domain.com, smtpserver, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4


# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is it a desktop, server, or cloud version? What is in your postfix config? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1505795/edit) and add these information.